# google maps timeline export

Tags: google-maps, json

I've exported my timeline from google maps using their takeout function to perform some perfunctory analyses on them, mainly because i'm curious. I've exported in JSON and I'm struggling to find the format the time is measured in it looks like X (being seconds/ milliseconds/nanoseconds) since some date advancing forward, but I can't for the life of me find out what and from what date.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like most of Google products, timeline export and bigquery db captured time as Unix timestamps in microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using BigQuery to analyze your exported timeline. You can check these articles to load and analyze:

- https://www.chipoglesby.com/2018/03/2018-analyzing-google-location-historyI/
- https://www.chipoglesby.com/2018/03/2018-analyzing-google-location-historyII/

Note that you will need to transform the exports before loading into BigQuery, the easiest way would be:

`jq -c '.locations[]'` (from the first post)

Timestamps are in milliseconds, transform with

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1486800415000)
2017-02-11 08:06:55 UTC
```